# Interpreting Java and converting it to another language

Tags: java, compiler-construction, interpreter, bytecode

I work with a language similar to JavaScript that is used for point-of-sale device programming. This language really s*cks and I'm trying to build some kind of framework in Java that "converts" Java code into this language.

I did this using some Regex and parsed the Java files directly. Now I found that this may be  not the right/better way and I'm searching for alternatives. Are there any tools for helping me doing so?

I thought I should use some advanced reflection utilities like ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/index.html). Performance is not crucial, so that may be the way. 
What do you think?

Comment: What kind of language are you using?

Comment: Surely you won't parse a context-free language using a regular language. You need a recursive-descent parser.

Comment: Maybe consider using Parboiled (https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) to build an AST and manipulate it?

Comment: It's called 'WMLScript'. It is similar to JavaScript, but the implementation is terrible. Thanks for the tips. I'll look into it.

Comment: While this is not for Java, the mechanism may help you understand what needs to be done. See: http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/fs2js.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a terrific parser-generator.  I'd look into it.  It has a Java grammar already available; I'm not sure if it's Java 5, 6, or 7 (I'm guessing it's 5).

Once you have the AST, your problem will be walking the tree and generating the target code.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to parse Java syntax with [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) or similar tool, [Java grammar description](http://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/download/contrib/grammars/Java1.5.zip) written long time ago. It can be used to write compiler so probably can also be used to write a converter. Regular expressions are not very good at parsing programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done anything with it myself, but you could take a look at one of the framework listed at [altjs.org](http://altjs.org/), specifically under the Java Ports section, and take a look at one of those frameworks and modify them to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways:

a) Interpret the bytecode. There are some existing interpreters in JS, e.g. DoppioVM. They can be very slow.

b) Compile bytecode to JS. I've seen at least one such attempt and the resulting JS was ugly and not very fast. But this approach can have a good performance (well, it may result in using HashMap instead of JS object and so on). The biggest issue is IMHO while/if reconstruction.

EDIT: OK, is possibly is not so slow, but it is ugly and contains garbage like `j2js.invokeStatic("j2js.client.Engine", "getEngine()j2js.client.Engine", null);`. The one compiler was https://github.com/decatur/j2js-compiler .

c) Compile Java to JS. You can try Google Web Toolkit or http://j2s.sourceforge.net/ .